# Bug in scikit-learns LDA function - plots shows non-zero correlation

Tags: python, r, scikit-learn, lda

I did some LDA using scikit-learn's LDA function and I noticed in my resulting plots that there is a non-zero correlation between LDs.

```
from sklearn.lda import LDA
sklearn_lda = LDA(n_components=2)
transf_lda = sklearn_lda.fit_transform(X, y)
```

This is very concerning, so I went back and used the Iris data set as reference. I also found in the scikit documentation the same non-zero correlation LDA plot, which I could reproduce.

Anyway, to give you an overview how it looks like

- Plot in the upper left: there is clearly something wrong here
- Plot in the lower left: This is on raw data, not a correct approach, but one attempt to replicate scikit's resuls
- Plots in the upper right and lower right: this is how it should actually look like.

[image]

I have put the code into [an IPython notebook](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/rasbt/pattern_classification/blob/test/test/linear_discriminant_analysis.ipynb) if you want to take a look at it and try it yourself.

The scikit-documentation that is consistent with the (wrong) result in the upper-left: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/decomposition/plot_pca_vs_lda.html

The LDA in R, which is shown in the lower right: http://tgmstat.wordpress.com/2014/01/15/computing-and-visualizing-lda-in-r/

Comment: There is a lot of variance scaling built-in to the scikit-learn LDA as it is now, [see here around line 160](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/lda.py). You might have better luck replicating the results by doing this - I personally don't like all the scaling by default, but this is one of the older algorithms in sklearn from what I understand. There are also multiple algorithms for LDA - I think there is actually a PR to implement a covariance based (with shrinkage) LDA now.

Comment: No matter of the scaling, there shouldn't be any correlation between the LDs. I don't know, but it really looks like that it is more than just a scaling problem!

Comment: Look at the sklearn code - then look at your code. There is variance normalization in the sklearn LDA that you are not doing, hence there are different answers.

Comment: @KyleKastner Hm, it looks like z-score normalization (scaling to unit variance) to me: that's what I am doing in the upper right. And what R is also doing by default. But it shouldn't matter whether you normalize (here: z-score) or mean-center the data; the result should be the same since units are measured on the same scale in this dataset (centimeters).

Comment: Lines 149:155 of the sklearn code do additional variance scaling within class which is different than just a standard scaler at input. Scalings then get normalized by standard deviation as well. Then there is another normalization (lines 169:174, second SVD) to project scalings to another, similar space. My guess is the algorithm you implemented called LDA is not the same as the algorithm *called* LDA in scikit-learn (which looks like a more specialized LDA with certain assumptions to me).

Comment: In addition, line 162 is doing a whitening of the first scaling components, which you also have not implemented. All these things are probably why your plots are different than sklearn's

Comment: @KyleKastner Thanks, I will experiment with the whitening transform a little bit. Anyways, the algorithm implemented scikit-learn is confusing and misleading since it obviously not doing an LDA in the way that it is commonly described in literature (e.g., the original 2-class LDA by Fisher, the generalized form by Rao for multiple classes, and described in the well-established "Pattern Classification" by Duda, Hart, and Stork). What's especially confusing is that it looks like the variables are correlated, which is totally the opposite of what should happen.

Comment: I answered further on the [Github issue](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/3500) you raised.

Comment: It would be great if you could pinpoint the differences and find out where exactly and how exactly the implementations do something different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was indeed a bug in the LDA's transform function: the classifier weights were erroneously applied after the actual transform. This has been fixed [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/3557). The changes have been merged into the master branch, so it should be in the 1.6 release of scikit-learn.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, now, what's going on (based on the [discussion GitHub](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/3500)) is that the LDA in scikit-learn's  doesn't have an orthonormal basis.

I want to post this as an answer to so that I close this question now. Thanks for the discussion!

### Scikit-learn

[image]

```
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
sklearn_pca = PCA(n_components=2)
transf_pca = sklearn_pca.fit_transform(transf_lda)
```

[image]

### Step-by-step approach

And for the comparison, here the step-by-step approach again

[image]